# training tesseract and multi page tiff

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I use tesseract 3.0.1 on windows 7 64 bit.

The documentation on training says:

> Each font should be put in a single multi-page tiff (**only if you are
>   using libtiff!**)

I'm not familiar with libtiff. I use ImageMagick to create multi-page tiff. So far this is working well, or at least seems to be. Am I expected to get some road blocks later on? If so what to do with libtiff - is it enough to run its setup or do I need to configure something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract doesn't care how you produced your multi-page tiff as long as it can read it with leptonica (which internally depends on libtiff). If tesseract can handle your tiff now, it can do the same for the rest of training process as well as run for OCR, so you are good to go.
I've produced my multi-page tiff with .Net standard library and tesseract had no problem with it.